Does the comma change everything in 'I support all the ones that gave it out, having all the new vaccines '?

Gemma Annette Bangs replied to to a FB comment ('This is totally
irresponsible! You MUST support the compulsory vaccination of every
MP, every rich person, every banker, all intelligence agencies, the
police, the judges and their families, all the medical professionals
and the staff of the pharma companies. I will personally provide the
experimental vaccine.')
'I support all the ones that gave it out, having all the new vaccines
'

Since her profile lists her job as 'cleaner', I suspect she didn't realize the comma reversed her intended meaning, did it?

You  should cite the source, so we can confirm the transcription. Is this something Gemma wrote, or a  transcription of what she said?  What do you think her intended meaning was?

I don't know who Gemma Annette Bangs is. Native Anglophone? The text is very clumsy - it's certainly not worth being syntactically analyzed by non-native speakers.

I’m voting to close this question because it's just about some garbage fb post

There's no "Learning" of English to be found here.  It's just poor English. Comma or no comma it's basically incomprehensible.

I wouldn't characterize the FB post as "garbage" but as a non-native speaker's production.  She simply said "having" instead of "having had".

You have here an anti-vaccine rant posing as a grammatical question.  I flagged it for mod intervention.

@TimR Would it be a native speaker's English to say, 'I support you having a swim every day'? Or 'I support my husband who provides for our family working abroad'?

Online comments and text messages are often written quickly, without much thought or editing. Don't waste time trying to analyze their syntax.
